# ERROR: line_locate_point: 1st arg is not a line

Tags: postgis

My test scenario is to confirm the image below, I select the points on the line in order of the direction the line was drawn.

[image: Order points]

I used the sql:

```
    Select
  testepoint."id" 
FROM
    testepoint
inner JOIN
    teste
ON
  ST_DWithin(teste.geom, testepoint.geom, 1) 
WHERE
    teste."id"= 1 
ORDER BY
  ST_Line_Locate_Point(teste.geom, testepoint.geom)
```

I placed the order by to sort the way I want, as the line was drawn

```
    ORDER BY
  ST_Line_Locate_Point(teste.geom, testepoint.geom)
```

And the error occurs:

```
 ERROR: line_locate_point: 1st arg is not a line
```

This was because my geometry is a MultiLineString. 
How can I do this sort of which is a MultiLineString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have some luck if you try passing your MultiLineString through "ST_LineMerge", depending on the actual geometry of your line. Try replacing:

```
ST_Line_Locate_Point(teste.geom, testepoint.geom)
```

with

```
ST_Line_Locate_Point(ST_LineMerge(teste.geom), testepoint.geom) )
```

If this doesn't work then your geometry is not convertible to a single linestring. You'll need to fix the MultiLineString and make sure it's all joined up correctly.

Comment: Thank you! It worked exactly as I wanted. 
You conehce a plugin so I can store the sqls ready so users can only run without change? 
Conehce or any article or example of developing a plugin for this purpose?